# Is it Possible to use PLAY framework in IBM Websphere Portal

Tags: playframework, websphere-portal

I am planning to modify my front end application with PLAY framework. My application is totally IBM Websphere Portal based and we are using SPRING/Hibernate at the back end.

Comment: Can any one please let me know is the above mentioned method is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Giving a quick look at the documentation of PLAY, I would say these are completely separate frameworks that can't be integrated without a large effort. Even if you do manage to integrate them I don't your support contract with IBM will support you if something goes wrong and you need help from IBM. If for no other reason, the ability to get support during a crit sit should sway you to stay within your support agreement.